# Straightforward modular arithmetic for power-of-two moduli

Tags: implementation, modular-arithmetic

Why if $q$ is a power-of-two integer, then doing arithmetic modulo $q$ (addition and multiplication) is very efficient and straightforward?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about simple mathematical operation's efficiency in computers and is not specific to cryptography.

Comment: its worth mentioning this can be cryptographically relevant --- one (significant) difference between the NIST PQC finalists Saber and Kyber are that Saber has a power-of-two moduli $2^{13}$ (and fast modular reduction), while Kyber uses an NTT friendly moduli, which admit more efficient (but more complex) multiplication algorithms. This has led to cryptographic research comparing the two, and even figuring out how to embed power-of-two multiplication into a NTT friendly ring.

Answer (score 3):

> Why if $q$ is a power-of-two integer, then doing arithmetic modulo $q$ (addition and multiplication) is very efficient and straightforward?

Because processors already have efficient addition and multiplication operations over moderately large ranges (32 or 64 bits), and the modulo operation is so efficient (just discard the bits above $q$, a simple *and* operation with a constant).  And, because for many operations (including addition and multiplication) the higher-order bits don't affect the lower-order bits, sometimes we don't even have to do that - we can just ignore them...